# Why is specifying a synchronization object in the lock statement mandatory

Tags: c#, synchronization, locking

I'm trying to wrap my mind around what exactly happens in the [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

If I understood correctly, the lock statement is syntactic sugar and the following...

```
Object _lock = new Object();

lock (_lock)
{
    // Critical code section
}
```

...gets translated into something roughly like:

```
Object _lock = new Object();

Monitor.Enter(_lock);
try
{
    // Critical code section
}
finally { Monitor.Exit (_lock); }
```

I have used the lock statement a few times, and always created a private field `_lock`, as a dedicated synchronization object. I do understand why you should not lock on public variables or types.

But why does the compiler not create that instance field as well? I feel there might in fact be situations where the developer wants to specify what to lock on, but from my experience, in most cases that is of absolutely no interest, you just want that lock! So why is there no parameterless overload of lock?

```
lock()
{
   // First critical code section
}

lock()
{
   // Second critical code section
}
```

would be translated into (or similar):

```
[DebuggerHidden]
private readonly object _lock1 = new object()

[DebuggerHidden]
private readonly object _lock2 = new object()

Monitor.Enter(_lock1);
try
{
    // First critical code section
}
finally { Monitor.Exit(_lock1); }

Monitor.Enter(_lock2);
try
{
    // Second critical code section
}
finally { Monitor.Exit(_lock2); }
```

**EDIT**: I have obviously been unclear concerning multiple lock statements. Updated the question to contain two lock statements.

Comment: Your suggestion seems like an equivalent to lock(this) which is not a very good idea.

Comment: @empi: no, it is not equivalent to `lock(this)` since _ lock is a _member_

Comment: @mousio: it will be equivalent functionally since there will be one lock object (_lock) for class instance

Comment: @empi: you just explained why it is _not_ equivalent; what about static methods requiring a lock?

Comment: I think what empi is trying to say, is that within the context of the class, using `lock(this)` is equivalent to the concept of `lock()`, however, mousio is stating that it is not equivalent, because outside the context of the class, other objects can still lock against the instance of the class, without locking against the `_lock` instance owned by the class.

Comment: @mousio: i'm talking only about op suggestion, that is: private readonly object _lock = new object()

Comment: @adabyron you already have an attribute that can be applied to a method for this `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`

Comment: @L.B: That is not the same, really. MethodImplOptions.Synchronized uses lock(this), which is not recommended if the class is public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the no-variable thing to work, you'd have to either:

- Have one auto-generated lock variable per lock block (what you did, which means that you can't have two different lock blocks locking on the same variable)
- Use the same lock variable for all lock blocks in the same class (which means you can't have two independent things protected)

Plus, you'd also have the issue of deciding whether those should be instance-level or static.

In the end, I'm guessing the language designers didn't feel that the simplification in one specific case was worth the ambiguity introduced while reading code.  Threading code (which is the reason to use locks) is already hard to write correctly and verify.  Making it harder would be a not-good thing.

Comment: Locking on the same variable requires the existing lock(var) overload (see comments in Christopher Harris and SergeyS answers). Instance/static variable is indeed a point, addressed to some extent in the comments of Hans Passants answer. I think the static modifier of the method containing the lock statement would determine the variable static modifier.

Comment: I do not really see the ambiguity. lock() would tell you instantly, without further investigations, that the lock is not shared. Writing the code would be easier, because you don't have to declare that variable (in the non-shared case). Misconceptions about the synchronization variable being the target of protection would decrease - all good things, in my book. However, I agree by now that the benefits are probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

The *state* of the lock needs to be stored.  Whether or not it was entered.  So that another thread that tries to enter the same lock can be blocked.

That requires a variable.  Just a very simple one, an plain object is enough.

A hard requirement for such a variable is that it is created *before* any lock statement uses it.  Trying to create it on-the-fly as you propose creates a new problem, there's a now a need to use a lock to safely create the variable so that only the first thread that enters the lock creates it and other threads trying to enter the lock are blocked until it is created.  Which requires a variable.  Etcetera, an unsolvable chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What does prevent the state to be stored for the compiler generated variable, though?

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question.

Comment: The fact that one may use different objects for more fine grained locking. The compiler can not sensibly deduct which object should hold the lock.

Comment: How is there a chicken-and-egg problem? If the field is initialized in a field initializer it is created by the thread that called the constructor. Surely there can be only 1 thread that calls a given object's constructor.

Comment: Now you are making dangerous assumptions about the scope of the locking variable.  It is certainly not appropriate to assume it can always be a non-static variable.  That won't protect a shared resource that has static scope, many do.

Comment: @HansPassant: True, that is about the best reason I've heard so far. However, isn't the association easy (lock in static method -> static variable, lock in non-static method -> non-static variable)? I agree that this gets a bit heavier on the compiler. Also, I kindly ask you to mark edits of your answer.

Comment: No, the lock itself gives no indication whatsoever what shared state is being protected.  That's implicit in the code inside the lock, they may be calls to methods located far away that manipulate variables that are not otherwise thread-safe.  Like the private variables of a List<>

Comment: @HansPassant: Locking will only make the encased block thread safe, not methods that are called from inside that block (those methods may be called from another point in code, and no lock state would be checked). So I would uphold that the static modifier of the method containing the lock statement determines the variable static modifier.

Comment: Not locking code that accesses a shared resource protected elsewhere by a lock is called a bug.  Really nasty one to find.  The kind of bug that would be particularly common if programmers were not forced to think about picking a lock state variable.

Comment: Just what I said. You would have to protect the method you are calling by its own lock, inside that method. I don't think this has anything to do with picking a lock state (synchronization) variable, and doesn't answer the static/non-static debate.
Also, coming back to your EDIT (chicken-and-egg problem), this variable is not generated at runtime, but at compile time.

Comment: That's a very dangerous way of thinking about locking.  It most certainly does not have anything to do with "protecting a method".  Locks protect *variables*, not code.  I seriously doubt we'll ever agree on a point of view, cold hard fact is that C# simply does not have the feature you want and most certainly will never get it.  Debating beyond that point is just not useful.  Bye.

Comment: Well, I found the debate (chat unfortunately) rather interesting up to this point, and don't think this is about views. If you can explain why it is dangerous, or why I should never get it, that would be just peachy and more to the point.

Answer (score 2):

There can be situations when you will need two different `lock`'s, which are independent of each other. Meaning when one 'lockable' part of code is locked other 'lockable' should not be locked. That's why there is ability to provide lock objects - you can have several of them for several independent `lock`'s

Comment: Every lock statement would of course create a separate compiler generated variable (name would have to be generated, the way anonymous types get names, for instance). But I understand your point turned around: sometimes you want to lock on the same variable, that's one reason why the parameterless version would have to be an overload.

Comment: @adabyron and how would you do locks on 2 methods synchronize then? You seem to only look at the degenerate case of one lock emthod ? one variable. Quite often you have multiple methods that use the same lock statement (count, put, get on a locked list).

Comment: @TomTom: in that case (which exists, as I already allowed in my question), use the _overload_ `lock(_userspecifiedvariable)`, as up to now.

Comment: @adabyron - they did not make parameterless overload because there is no real benefits of it, but a huge cost of compiler team development:) You can think about it as 'nice to have'.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing for an implicit lock object might encourage the use of a single lock object, which is considered bad practice. By enforcing the use of an explicit lock object, the language encourages you to name the lock something useful, such as "countIncementLock".

A variable named thusly would not encourage developers to use the same lock object when performing a completely separate operation, such as writing to a stream of some kind.

Therefore, the object could be writing to a stream on one thread, while incrementing a counter on another thread, and neither of the threads would necessarily interfere with each other.

The only reason why the language wouldn't do this is because is because it would look like a good practice, but in reality would be hiding a bad practice.

**Edit:**

Perhaps the designers of C# did not want implicit lock variables because they thought it might encourage bad behavour.

Perhaps the designers did not think of implicit lock variables at all, because they had other more important things to think about first.

If every C# developer knew exactly what was happening when they wrote `lock()`, and they knew the implications, then there's no reason why it shouldn't exist, and no reason why it shouldn't work how you're suggesting.

Comment: I think you are making the same point as SergeyS. In my suggestion, every lock statement gets one synchronization variable. The developer would have no way to lock on the same variable. I might have to update the question to make this clear.

Comment: @ababyron, My point is not exactly the same as @SergeyS'. I'm attempting to answer the question `why does the compiler not create that instance field as well?`, but without addressing the validity of the answer itself. For instance, just because the compiler *doesn't* do it, doesn't mean it *shouldn't* do it. Perhaps theres a perfectly valid use case for what you're suggesting. What my answer presupposes is, "what if there shouldn't be an implicit lock variable?"

Comment: I never wanted to replace lock(var). It would just be a parameterless overload.

Comment: Right. I completely understand that. Before, I assumed you wanted a single instance of a lock variable for all `lock()`'s within a class. You then stated that each would have it's own instance. That makes a lot more sense. Still, a lot of compiler-team time and effort would go into implementing this feature, and I'm sure the idea has just been pushed back in favor of other features.